# How to detect which file was opened to launch application

Tags: c#, .net

I am will be using [this class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43675/C-FileAssociation-Class) to set file associations for my program. How would i fetch the path of which file was opened to launch the application? I searched that class for one, and didn't spot one anywhere, and I have searched google and MSDN for the last few hours with no results. I don't have any sample code as I have absolutely no clue.

Any help is thanked and will be welcome.

Comment: Did you read the comments in that article? It seems pretty outdated and no more recommended by its own author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename for the file that was selected, causing your application to open, will be passed as a command line parameter. If this is a program where you're writing the Main function, the array of strings passed to the function will contain the information you need.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

Another option, if you aren't writing Main yourself, is to call

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
```

See this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx for more information about how to use this function.